# How do I parse date strings with time zones like 'G8T' and 'G12T'?

Tags: .net, parsing, datetime, http-headers

In an ASP.NET application, I need to check the modified date when retrieving some images from a remote server.  The header values for "Last-Modified" are strings like the following:

- Thu, 08 Dec 2011 19:57:12 G12T
- Thu, 14 Aug 2003 16:13:20 G8T

.NET's `DateTime.Parse()` method fails on these with a `FormatException` ("The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 26.").  Are there options I can pass to make a(ny) parsing method recognize those time zone indicators?  I have not seen them before, and [a Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=time+zone+%22g8t%22+%22g12t%22) turns up some apparent usages on forums and similar sites, but no helpful information about what they mean.

(Oddly, the header values for "Date" on the same images end with "GMT".  The remote server is IIS 7.5.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't easily check right now, but this *might* work:

```
DateTimeOffset result = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(text,
    "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'G'z'T'",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

That's using the [`z` custom specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zSpecifier)... which would always *format* with a sign, but may not require one when *parsing*.

If you're happy to use bleeding-edge code, I believe [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) 1.2 (unreleased) should be able to cope with that using an `OffsetDateTimePattern` of `ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'G'o<-H>'T'`. Again, I can't test that right now but I'd *expect* it to work. It does mean running with currently-unreleased code though...

Comment: +1 Wrote with a Nokia 3510 few seconds before a parachute jump

Comment: That call also generates a FormatException ("String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.").  Thank you for the tip about Noda Time.  I will look into it if I can't find anything else that works.

Comment: @Kimberly: Right, it's probably the lack of a sign :( If you wanted to stick with the .NET types you could do some string manipulation to get the final bit into a more friendly format...

Comment: I ended up doing as suggested in Jon's last comment - RegEx manipulation and replacement in order to be able to parse with built-in types and methods.  (Too much time has passed to post the details as my own answer, so I'm accepting this for the Noda Time suggestion, which is probably a great idea, and for that comment.)